# d3.js xAxis not displaying

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have issues on d3.js (first time experiencing javascript so hard :o )

I want, in live, to display data from database. Everything works great but I have  little issues. When I call my function updateData : boom, my xAxis disappears :(

Screen of the issue : http://hpics.li/d725f64

I used this code : 
https://gist.github.com/Majella/5fc4cd5f41a6ddf2df23

I modified some part so my code is :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var margin = {
        top: 35,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 35,
        left: 40
    },
    width = 1120,
        height = 480;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;

    var formatTime = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S");

    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S"));

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate('linear')
        .x(function (d) {
        return x(d.timestamp);
    })
        .y(function (d) {
        return y(d.value);
    });


    var tip = d3.tip()
        .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
        .offset([-10, 0])
        .html(function (d) {
        return "<strong>Value:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.value + "</span><br/><strong>Date:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.timestamp + "</span>";
    })

    var svg = d3.select("#livefeed").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")

        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.call(tip);

    svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    d3.json("./data.php", function (error, data) {
        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.timestamp = /*parseDate(*/
            d.timestamp /*)*/
            ;
            d.value = +d.value;
        });

        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
            return d.timestamp;
        }));
        y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
            return d.value;
        }));

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", 240)
            .attr("y", 430)
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("(TIME)");

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("(LIVE)");

        var path = svg.append("g")
            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
            .append("path")
            .data(data)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("fill", "pink");

        var inter = setInterval(function () {
            updateData();
        }, 5000);
    });

    function updateData() {
        d3.json("./data.php", function (data) {
            data.forEach(function (d) {
                d.timestamp = d.timestamp;
                d.value = +d.value;
            });

            x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
                return d.timestamp;
            }));
            y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
                return d.value;
            }));

            svg.select("path.line")
                .attr("d", line(data));

            svg.select(".x.axis")
                .transition()
                .duration(750)
                .ease("linear")
                .call(xAxis);

            svg.select(".y.axis")
                .transition()
                .duration(750)
                .ease("linear")
                .call(yAxis);

            svg.select("path")
                .transition()
                .duration(750)
                .ease("linear")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ")");

            data.shift();

        });
    };
});
```

Also, I was wondering how to shift the chart. For instance I want to display only 10 minutes. At 11minutes, the first minute goes out and the 11th goes in.

Thanks !

Comment: Is `d.timestamp` a number both initially and after an update?

Comment: Yes. 
In fact, initially, the chart is not drawn. I just have axis -like I want- with labels & lines. 
When an update is called to draw the chart, I have a the data I want drawn on the chart. But the line of xAxis (yAxis doesn't have this issue) disappears.

EDIT : 
I just delete .transition() from 
svg.select(".x.axis")
   .transition()
 .duration(750)
 .ease("linear")
 .call(xAxis);

Comment: EDIT : 
I just delete .transition() from 
`svg.select(".x.axis")
   .transition()
 .duration(750)
 .ease("linear")
 .call(xAxis);`

On console, I've got :
TypeError: svg.select(...).duration is not a function basic.js:110:0

But my xAxis line is displayed...
Don't know why...

Comment: Could you double check what `x.domain()` is after an update? The axis is not touched probably because the `.call(xAxis)` (which followed the `.transition()` call) is not executed. `.duration()` is only defined on a `transition` and not on general `selection`s in `d3`.

Comment: Problem solved : 
On my `updateData()`

`svg.select("path")
   .transition()
 .duration(750)
 .ease("linear")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ")");`

I was translating path which apparently included the x Axis.
I renamed my variable path to pathl (the one who draw data) and now my xAxis is not hidden.

Thanks all!